# Mechanism of Windows UAC Shield/Buckler appendage on .exe files

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-shell

I have written a simple program.

Recently I found that when giving it a name including `update` as its substring (case insensitive), the file automatically gets a Windows shield/buckler on it in Windows Explorer.

In the following image, all files are identical except for different file names:

[image]

I was wondering if this is because there is a `UAC Shield/Buckler Appendage Mechanism` in Windows Explorer and its backend parts.

Any suggestions and clues are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a manifest file is the solution.

Due to the Installer Detection Technology of UAC, a UAC shield icon will be displayed on your 32-bit executable file with no `requestedExecutionLevel` in the manifest, but with keywords like “install”, “setup”, “update” etc in the filename.  With the UAC shield icon, if we launch the executable file, the UAC elevation dialog will pop up.

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/site/silentsignin?returnUrl=https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/uac-prompts-on-any-program-with-the-word-patch-or/c5359497-d16e-43c6-99f2-db3d8eecc9c0)

The manifest should contain a `requestedExecutionLevel`. Here is an example of a partial manifest file:

```
 <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133337/how-do-i-avoid-uac-when-my-exe-file-name-contains-the-word-update) for more info.

Comment: More info https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works

Comment: I tried with a simple external manifest file with a [help link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1) and it indeed affects the UAC buckler showing behavior. Thanks a million!